# (node) Get rest status result in a function with unirest

Tags: node.js, unirest

my first steps with node...

I want to access to the response status when calling a function like this:

```
 var unirest = require('unirest');

function doPut(){

var Request = unirest.put('some_url').type('json').send('some_json');

return Request.end(function (response) {

            return response.status;

            });


}

console.log("Status is: " + doPut())
```

Inside the inner code, the value of status is "204" but when asking outside the function doput() i get an object,how can I pass the value from the inner function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason [object Object] is returned is because you're just printing the object. Either (if you know the output format) print a specific value or use `JSON.stringify(doput())`.

Comment: Yeah, is an object... with uri,auth,content-type...... maybe is the "Request" object why is not the response.status that I want to pass??